# How do I Perform evasive maneuvers?

Tags: spaceteam

In Spaceteam, one of the instructions that can be given is to Perform evasive maneuvers. I asked my friend to do this, but they responded that it was not a function that they had, nor did I notice a panel on my screen that had this option. I hadn't encountered it before. Does this involve physically moving one's device in some way or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Evasive Maneuvers, take them!]

According to [this screenshot](https://twitter.com/brwnx/status/302476381806276608), it does not involve physically moving one's device in some way, but pressing a button. One of you must've had a translator malfunction.